# Chinese locale removes question mark from URL

Tags: xslt

After further analysis, I have found that problem is while rendering webpage OR XSL file.
When I do "View Source" I find that in URL "?" is replaced with " ".

I mean, I have written a line in XSL as `something.asp?name=sameer`  but when i do "View Source", same line is displayed as `something.asp&nbsp;name=sameer`

This happens only if Windows locale is Chinese.  It does not happen with English

Comment: How are you switching to the Chinese locale? Maybe posting some of the code would help us diagnose the problem. You have to remember that we know nothing about your ASP application how it works or is set-up. The more detail you can provide the more likely you will receive relevant answers.

Comment: I am switching using Windows Control Panel --> "Regional and Language Options".  My code is: <script  LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
           document.write(Button('  <xsl:eval>GetUIString4JS(me, "Edit")</xsl:eval>  ', 'JavaScript: EditPage("ConDet.asp?POSITION=1&amp;PAGEID=<xsl:value-of select="//ConDet/PageId"/>&amp;FOLDERID=<xsl:value-of select="//ConDet/FolderId"/>")', 'cmdEdit'))
          </script>

Comment: What does `Button()` do?, is it another JavaScript function, could you include the code? Looks like it's doing some sort of XSL transformation to build the string written by `document.write()`. So far I'm not sure how of this relates to Classic ASP, this is all client-side code.

Comment: Yes. Basically this is a code from XSL file which comes in picture when user clicks on a button. I cannot post complete code.

Comment: In that case can't really help you, but can't you just HTML encode the `?` so replace `?` with `&#63;` in your string?